# login control forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, login-control

I setup a login control to use on my web application and having issues validating the users. I created the membership tables in my own database in sql server 2008 using a suggestion on another site. Then I opted to just use forms authentication and created two users in the WSAT and thought that this would work fine. But it returns false for all users including the two I created. Why this is so I am not sure and if I were to use the sql database tables how would I do this?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
 </authentication>
<authorization>
     <allow users="boy"/>
     <allow users="girl"/>
</authorization>
<roleManager enabled="true" />
```

code behind login:

```
If Page.IsValid then
   If username <>"" and password <>"" then
       If FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username,passwprd) = False then
           Return false
       else
           response.redirect("~/default.aspx")
       End If
  End If
 End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your web.config to use the `MembershipProvider`.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx) for more info. Are you trying to use the `SqlMembershipProvider`?

To authenticate using `MembershipProvider` use the `Login` user control or you can create your own and call the following methods:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
{
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
   FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, createPersistentCookie); 
}
```

Comment: Yes...one question. After adding the membership provider code and adding a new user I saw the user added to the users table in sql db. But user still denied access. Do I need the code behind the login like I have if formsauthentication.authenticate()